# Which android devices have optimized encryption hardware?

Tags: security, battery-life, encryption

I've been using a Nexus 5 for a while and using FS encryption. Apple's iOS Security document states that:

> Every iOS device has a dedicated AES 256 crypto engine built into the DMA path
>   between the flash storage and main system memory, making file encryption highly
>   efficient. Along with the AES engine, SHA-1 is implemented in hardware, further reducing
>   cryptographic operation overhead.

Do any of the Android devices have such hardware to reduce encryption overhead? Is it part of a standard like iOS?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but you might find some of the links in the answers to this previous question helpful: [Hardware backed Credentials Storage on Galaxy Nexus](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55564/)

Comment: Encryption on Android uses the dm-crypt layer in the Linux kernel.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fundamentally Android requires the developer to implement encryption directly (ie, there is no OS supplied framework for this).

To the best of my knowledge, there is no current Android hardware with Encryption built into to the hardware.  The new "Black Phone" that Boeing is reportedly making for the US defense industry is likely an exception to this (the phone HW was specifically engineered for security).

Basically iOS is encrypted by default, and Android requires the devloper to implement encryption in their applications.

Comment: Android has full-device storage encryption. It doesn't make a lot of sense to say the developer has to implement encryption directly. The Java standard library has several encryption features too.

Comment: Some devices do have hardware backed keystores which holds key pairs http://nelenkov.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/credential-storage-enhancements-android-43.html

Comment: This changed since I wrote this, as Android now does support encryption directly.